How to set up gitlab ci/cd jo to run on multiple rules?
based on the gitlab docs, one can trigger a job in the ci/cd pipeline vi api.  I have put a rules condition, see below
  rules:
    --if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "api"
    --if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"

I would also like this stage to be triggered via cron job as well, so i added another rule => --if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
I would like this job to run on only these two rules, one when triggered via api and on cron . do these two rules suffice, such that this doesn't get triggerd via any other situation?
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"

test-job1:
  rules:
    --if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "api"
  stage: test
  script:
    - python3 mydumbscript.py $arg1 $arg2 $arg3

